# Get Registry Value into a variable in a batch file and use it in an if case

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to get a Registry Value (in my case true or false) and depending on the state (true or false) I would like to execute some commands.

I have found a few answers that might be working, but i was unable to get them to work (I'm not experienced with batch files at all)

Now to the more case specific question. I am changing a registry value depending on if my PC is in Sleep or Active. I now want to read the registry value and if the value is true (which means the PC is active) I want the script to do nothing, but if the value is false (which means the PC is in Sleep) I want to execute a few commands that will wake the PC from Sleep, wait 30 minutes and put the PC back to sleep.

I really would appreciate examples if I'm not asking for too much.

In my case I change the value with the following commands:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Current_State /t REG_SZ /v Status_Active /d true /f
```

or

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Current_State /t REG_SZ /v Status_Active /d false /f
```

My idea was to check the value inside an if case and do actions depending on the value, but I have no idea how I should do that.

Additional info from the command section to better express what I'm looking for:

Yeah that's right, my PC is already waking itself from sleep at 1am and goes back into sleep 30 minutes later (or whatever i use in the script, its 1800 seconds atm). I am also changing a registry entry from true to false depending one the state I'm in, "true" if I am using it and "false" if the PC is already in sleep. I now only need to check which value the registry entry has and depending on that use a few commands(if the value is false) or not (if the value is true)

And here is a picture where the registry entry is located if that helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOV8V.png it is the "Status_Active" one which changes from true to false and  vice versa

My solution (quote from the comment section):

I have found a workaround to that, I'm now using a one liner after the reg query command:

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 
   (echo PC is Active & Echo Aborting Operations) 
else 
   (echo PC was Sleeping & echo Continue Operation & timeout /t 3600 /nobreak & rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0)
```

Comment: When PC is in the sleep mode all programs are suspended including your batch file.

Comment: I am executing the batch file with the task planner, you can wake the PC from Sleep that way

Comment: Ok i should have phrased it diffrently, what i meant is that I put my PC to sleep when i leave, the task planner than wakes the PC from Sleep at 1am, starts a batch file which waits 30 minutes and puts the PC back to sleep, but the task planner will also activate the task that wakes the PC and starts the batch file to put it back to sleep after 30 minutes so even if im using the PC it will go into sleep at 1:30am , to prevent that i write a registry entry which has either true or false as a value and i want to read which value is active when i run the batch file to prevent

Comment: that my PC shuts down when its marked as active so that it only goes to sleep if it is makred as sleep. I made two scripts, one that just changes the script to active at 0:59am but only runs if the PC is active (i disabled it to start when the PC is in sleep mode) so every time it runs im using the PC at 0:59am and as long as that is the case i want the otehr script to not put my PC into Sleep again. So it only puts the PC into Sleep after 30 minutes if  wasnt using the PC when the first script runs at 0:59am

Comment: So what you're saying that you already have the _sleep_/_WakeUp_ "engine" you only need the registry access functionality from the `.bat` file?

Comment: Yeah thats right, my PC is already waking itself from sleep at 1am and goes back into sleep 30 minutes later (or whatever i use in the script, its 1800 seconds atm. I am also changing a regestry entry from true to false depending one the state im in, "true" if i am using it and "false" if the PC is already in sleep. I now only need to check which value the registry entry has and depenging on that use a few commands(if the value is false) or not (if the value is true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we can use (as you already are) the [reg utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx), but in a form slightly different that you pointed out: instead of having a (`boolean`) value that will store the computer state we'll use the existence/not existence of a registry key (as opposed to most of *Ux* shells *Win* `cmd` shell is not smart enough to be able to assign a command output to an environment variable), but we can use the return code.

So, considering the registry **key**: `HKCU\Software\Current_State\Sleeping` (no subkeys or values required under it), we will use it as a flag: when the computer goes to sleep, it will create it, when it wakes up, it will delete it.

Here's the `.bat` file skeleton:

@Edit1: First time I tried this `.bat` on *XP*, and it ran OK with/without the key present. When moving to *W7*, when the key is present it *apparently* executes all the statements. That is because of the (enclosing) paranthesis from the first echo command (which indicate that the `if` block ends there). They need to be escaped (I will also try this on *XP*):

```
@echo off
set SENTINEL_KEY=HKCU\Software\Current_State\Sleeping
reg query %SENTINEL_KEY%
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo command returned 0 ^(success^), the key was found ^(the computer is sleeping^)
    echo do your extra operations here
    echo you might want to delete the key just before waking up the computer if you're not doing that from some place else
    echo delete the key using: reg delete %SENTINEL_KEY% /f
) else (
    echo command returned !=0 ^(1, error^), the key was not found ^(the comuter is awake^)
)
```

Comment: Yeah thank you very much, as far as i can tell that will get my job done, I'm going to sleep now and I will check that tomorrow.

Comment: I still have some trouble with the if case, regardless of the outcome from the reg query the file does execute both commands, the if and the else case.
I have a script that runs every day at 0:59am and deletes the sleeping key, waits 3 minutes (in this time the other script starts to check for the registry key, this script runs at 1:00 am) the first one then adds the key again afterwards, that means the second script would have noticed the key is missing and the PC is therefor running. If the first script was not executed (which means the PC was sleeping) the key is still in the registry and

Comment: the PC goes into sleep after it did its job.
Picure of my batch files: http://i.imgur.com/iAJooS0.png
the CHeck status batch file runs at 0.59am and the Sleep 1 hour batch file runs at 1.00am

Comment: So, if you run the .batch file manually, it executes both branches? Or only from _Task Scheduler_? Anyway it shouldn't behave like you're saying. 3 things: who is waking up the computer? Setting the computer to sleep and deleting the key should be done from the same place. `timeout` and `rundll32` are they executed in sleep mode? According to [SetSuspendState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373201(v=vs.85).aspx) the 2nd argument is ignored (unless W2k3).

Comment: Yes, if i run it manually, it doesnt matter if the registry Key exists or not, it executed both branches.
I have found a workaround to that, im now using a one liner after the reg queary command:
"if %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo PC is Active & Echo Aborting Operations) else (echo PC was Sleeping & echo Continue Operation & timeout /t 3600 /nobreak & rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0)"

Comment: So, there was a problem with my `.bat` file. Did you try again with my @Edit1 changes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I didnt, I searched for a similar if case and used that instead, its basically the same i guess, i edited the inital post :) thanks for your help